# Compare form inputs with database values

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a form for adding attributes to products.
The attributes are added by appending to form table from checkboxes with jquery.
Everithing is working great except when i want to remove an attribute from a product.

```
 if(isset($_POST['product_attribute'])){
  foreach ($_POST['product_attribute'] as $product_attribute) {
    if($product_attribute['attribute_id']) {
          $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id ='%d' AND attribute_id='%d'", (int)$product_id, (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id']);
          $database->delete($query);

       foreach ($product_attribute['product_attribute_description'] as $product_attribute_description) {
          $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO product_attribute SET product_id='%d', attribute_id='%d', text='%s'", (int)$product_id, (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id'], $product_attribute_description['text']);
          $database->insert($query);

        }
    }
  }
}else{
  $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id = '%d'", $product_id);
  $database->delete($query);
}
```

Here are my js functions

```
function setAttributes() {
    $s('div.attributes .form_attribute_name').each(function() {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            var val = $s(this).val().split("|");
            var id_att = $s(this).attr('id').split("_");
            var identic = 0;
            $s('tr.attrClass').each(function() {
                var tr_id_att = $s(this).attr('id').split('_');
                if (tr_id_att[1] == id_att[1]) {
                    identic++;
                }
            })
            if (identic == 0) {
                $s('.table tr.information').remove();
                addAttribute(val[0], val[1], id_att[1]);
            }
        } else {
            var id_att = $s(this).attr('id').split('_');
            $s('#attribute-row_' + id_att[1]).remove();
        }
    });
}
var attribute_row = 0;

function addAttribute(name, value, id) {
    if (id == undefined) {
        id = "";
    }
    if (name == undefined) {
        name = "";
    }
    if (value == undefined) {
        value = "";
    }

    html = '<tr id="attribute-row_' + id + '" class="attrClass">'
    html += '<td>';
    html += '<input type="text" value="' + name + '" name="product_attribute[' + id + '][name]" />';
    html += '<input type="hidden" value="' + id + '" name="product_attribute[' + id + '][attribute_id]" />';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '<td><textarea name="product_attribute[' + id + '][product_attribute_description][2][text]"></textarea>';
    html += '<td><a class="bluebtn" id="delrow" onclick="$s(\'#attribute-row_' + id + '\').remove();">Inlatura</a></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $s('tbody').append(html);
    attribute_row++;
}
```

Html table

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="product-update" id="product-update" method="post">
                    <div class="attributes-to-product">
                            <a class="bluebtn" id="set-attribute" onclick="setAttributes();">Seteaza</a>
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Atributul</th>
                                        <th>Text</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {if $atribute}
                                    {section name=li loop=$atribute.attribute_id}
                                    <tr id="attribute-row_{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}" class="attrClass">
                                        <td><input type="text" name="product_attribute[{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}][name]" value="{$atribute.name[li]}" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" name="product_attribute[{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}][attribute_id]" value="{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}" /></td>
                                        <td><textarea name="product_attribute[{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}][product_attribute_description][2][text]">{$atribute.text[li]}</textarea></td>
                                        <td><a class="bluebtn" id="delrow" onclick="$s('#attribute-row_{$atribute.attribute_id[li]}').remove();">Inlatura</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {/section}
                                    {else}
                                    <tr class="information">
                                        <td colspan="3" align="center">Nu aveti setat niciun atribut</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {/if}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
</form>
```

How can I compare the database attribute entries for the specific product i want to modify with form inputs?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what is happening? Why doesn't it work? What error are you getting?

Comment: the attributes are added with jquery by appending to form. The insert and update is working. When i try to remove an attribute, he doesn't.  I have to remove all of them to work.

Comment: Can you show your jquery also?

Comment: edited now with jquery functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
if(isset($_POST['product_attribute'])){
    $att_id = array();
  foreach ($_POST['product_attribute'] as $product_attribute) {

    $att_id[] = $product_attribute['attribute_id'];

    if($product_attribute['attribute_id']) {
          $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id ='%d' AND attribute_id='%d'", (int)$product_id, (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id']);
          $database->delete($query);

       foreach ($product_attribute['product_attribute_description'] as $product_attribute_description) {
          $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO product_attribute SET product_id='%d', attribute_id='%d', text='%s'", (int)$product_id, (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id'], $product_attribute_description['text']);
          $database->insert($query);
      }
    }
  }

    $vals = implode(",", $att_id);
    $query = "DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id = $product_id AND attribute_id NOT IN($vals)";
    $database->delete($query);
}else{
    $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id = '%d'", $product_id);
    $database->delete($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not understand what you want or where is the mistake, but i like gamble and i try to answer at your question.
But, first, i wanna try to explain that debug/correct/help user without code is not so simple. You use jQuery tag, but i didn't see jQuery code, and maybe the problem is in that part of code.

Now i'll come back to my gamble, if i understand the problem, you wanna remove an attribute of an html tag, so why not try with jQuery.removeAttr() function?

Comment: I want to compare form inputs with database and remove the values that are not in the form

Comment: Ok maybe I understand, you need to build a "complex" query 
DELETE FROM XXX WHERE some_field NOT IN(list of values passed from form)